# Wired Network Issue: Looping in wire unplugged to trying to connect at 10mbps to wire unplugged

Tags: network-manager

A fresh install of a dual boot Ubuntu 22.4 cannot connect to wired network.

The motherboard is a `Gigabyte H510M H` and here is what the syslog says

```
Feb  9 11:29:25 michel-H510M-H NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1707474565.2123] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Feb  9 11:29:25 michel-H510M-H NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1707474565.2128] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb  9 11:29:25 michel-H510M-H kernel: [  874.327060] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-300:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 10Mbps, check cabling!
Feb  9 11:29:25 michel-H510M-H kernel: [  874.327082] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 10Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control off
Feb  9 11:29:26 michel-H510M-H NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1707474566.6487] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb  9 11:29:26 michel-H510M-H kernel: [  875.762980] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
Feb  9 11:29:53 michel-H510M-H NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1707474593.1639] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
```

The same computer connect without any issue in windows. We tried different cables.

Any idea ?